# Rewriting Excel formula to R code

Tags: r, excel

A while ago I used this excel formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,$C2,A:A,$A2,E:E,$AC$1)>1
```

in order to find if there are more than one row with same 2 records (in col C and A) and if they have in E value specified in AC1.
I was looking to write the same statement/formula using R but I didn't had much success with it.

Wonder if someone had idea how it should be written or a different, possibly better approach to do that. Sorry for my english and possilby poor explenation of the problem.

Comment: You are probably looking for the set operations in R e.g. `intersect` So you might have a function like `length(intersect(A,B)) > 1`. See `?intersect`.

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` can be simulated with `ifelse` and `cumsum` but I'm not clear on what you are doing here.